# Making room for larger title in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am doing some plots in which I would like to add some text info. Normally this is just a single line and I use the `title` field for this, and it works perfectly out of the box. Now I want to add some more information and the title is overlapping the plot, which is ugly. Here is an example:

```py
import numpy
import plotly.express as px

px.ecdf(
    numpy.random.randn(99),
    title = 'Title<br><sup>Subtitle</sup><br><sup>Some info that I want to display for this plot</sup><br><sup>Some other info I would like to hardcode here</sup>',
).write_html('plot.html',include_plotlyjs='cdn')
```

[image]

How can I compress the plot vertically, from the top, such that there is more room for this larger title?

Comment: Try this: `fig = px.ecdf(...);fig.update_layout(title_y=0.95);fig.write_html('plot.html',include_plotlyjs='cdn');fig.show()`

Comment: @r-beginners, not the optimal solution but helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the room above the graph -> increase the top margin (default is `100`) :

```py
fig = px.ecdf(
    numpy.random.randn(99),
    title = 'Title<br><sup>Subtitle</sup><br><sup>Some info that I want to display for this plot</sup><br><sup>Some other info I would like to hardcode here</sup>',
)

fig.update_lyout(margin_t=150)

fig.write_html('plot.html',include_plotlyjs='cdn')
```

See layout [`margin_t`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-margin-t).